# Reformulation logical AND in integer programming maximization problem

Tags: numerical-methods, linear-programming, integer-programming, linearization, binary-programming

Suppose we have variables $x_1,x_2,y \in \{0,1\}$ such that $y=1$ if and only if $x_1 = x_2 = 1$ and we want maximize the value of $y$. I know that this reduces to the following Integer programming problem:
\begin{align*}
\max y&\\
x_1,x_2, y \in \{0,1\}\\
y \leq x_1\\
y\leq x_2.\\
\end{align*}

The linear relaxation of this problem is then given by:
\begin{align*}
\max y&\\
0\leq x_1,x_2, y \leq 1\\
y \leq x_1\\
y\leq x_2.\\
\end{align*}
Now in the relaxation we will simply get $y=\min\{x_1,x_2\}$. I was wondering whether there is some alternative formulation for the Integer Program such that, when we take the linear relaxation of the problem, the solution $y$ is stricly smaller than $\min\{x_1,x_2\}$. See also [here](https://www.math.u-bordeaux.fr/~fvanderb/papers/RDslides.pdf) for more information about reformulations.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This reformulation relies on the optimality condition that $y$ is maximized.  The constraints enforce only $y\le \min(x_1,x_2)$, and $y< \min(x_1,x_2)$ is feasible but not optimal.  If your problem has a different objective, you can instead impose an additional linear constraint $y \ge x_1 + x_2 - 1$ to enforce $(x_1=1 \land x_2=1) \implies y=1$, as described [here](https://or.stackexchange.com/questions/37/how-to-linearize-the-product-of-two-binary-variables).

Comment: I am looking for an alternative formulation such that the difference between the optimal solution for the linear relaxation and the integer program is smaller.

Comment: The constraints $y\le x_1,y\le x_2,y\ge x_1+x_2-1,y\ge 0$ form the convex hull of the feasible points $\{(x_1,x_2,y)\in\{0,1\}^3:y=x_1 x_2\}$, so you won't find a tighter formulation.

Comment: Important note: the $x_i$ may also change value by the rest of the integer programming problem, this is only a small part of a much bigger problem. The $y$ only appears here

Comment: But so I figure the answer is: no

Comment: I understand the reasoning, thanks for the reply.